# question about installing Rally on OpenStack

Tags: benchmark, openstack

I have a quick question that I'm going to install Rally to benchmark OpenStack and I've read it's documents [here](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Rally/installation).
Now, I don't know if I install Rally on a vm in OpenStack that there's no service on it, Rally will work properly?
Would Rally benchmark services on OpenStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Rally on anywhere which can talk to Openstack REST APIs.

Rally is using OpenStack API.
actually python clients like this one https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient.

Rally should have HTTP access to this OpenStack API
it means that:

1) No Rally shouldn't work together on the same servers where OpenStack works

2) It should be have access to OpenStack

+Thanks a lot to "boris-42" and "yingjun" on "#openstack-rally" channel for their help and guidance.